# Passing An Ng-Model Value to A Directive

Tags: angularjs

I've looked at the previous answers, but I'm not sure if they are the answer I need or not.

I have a directive, let's call it "selectValue". A value can have a default, let's call it "$scope.default".

The directive will look like this in one place:

```
<select-value ng-model="data.input" controlId="inputSelector" />
```

But it will look like this in another:

```
<select-value ng-model="myValue" controlId="inputSelector" />
```

I do not have the option of making the ng-model inputs the same; they are used in different places and this is a legacy code base.

Here is the definition of the directive:

```
    .directive('selectValue', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {

    const directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            controlId: '@',  
            model: '=?'
        },
        controller: 'selectValueCtrl',
        template: '<input id="{{controlId}}" name="{{controlId}}" placeholder="Enter Value" type="text" ng-model="model" />'
    };

    return directive;
}
```

The question: what do I do to be able to enter different inputs in the "model" attribute of the `<select-value>` to have it access different scope variables?

Edit: the referenced "duplicate" question refers to setting a value for ng-click, not referencing ng-model in a form control.

Comment: have you tried `model: '@' ` for binding the scope in the directive?

Comment: One should avoid using self-closing syntax with element directives. It will cause unexpected behavior with HTML5. Always include the closing tag `</select-value>`.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, it looks as though you are trying to pass defaults with preset values. The problem you are facing is your select-value element is using the ng-model directive in an attempt to pass the data however your binding in your directive is 'model'.

In order to fix this issue, simply change the '**ng-model**' to '**model**' and your bindings should then work.

In the end, your element should look like so:

```
<select-value model="myValue" controlId="inputSelector" />
```

as opposed to:

```
<select-value ng-model="myValue" controlId="inputSelector" />
```

Comment: One should avoid using self-closing syntax with element directives. It will cause unexpected behavior with HTML5. Always include the closing tag `</select-value>`.