# AngularJS Bound Ng-Model Inside Directive Has Wrong Attribute Name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is a followup to a previous question. I have some questions on the rendering of a custom directive and the actual output in the DOM when the page is rendered.

Here is the definition of my directive:

```
angular.module('moduleName)
    .directive('selectValue', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {

    const directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            controlId: '@',  
            model: '=?'
        },
        controller: 'selectValueCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'template.html'

    };

    return directive;
}
```

Here is the externalized template:

```
<!-- template.html -->
<input id="{{controlId}}" name="{{controlId}}" placeholder="Enter Value" 
       type="text" ng-model="model" />
```

Given the following use of the directive:

```
<select-value controlId="selectValue" model="data.value"></selectValue>
```

Why does it render as the following:

```
<input id="selectValue" ng-model="model" />
```

Instead of:

```
<input id="selectValue" ng-model="data.value" />
```

Did I make a mistake in my code, or is this expected behavior?

Comment: I'm sort of surprised this works - shouldn't the `controlId` attribute on your `<select-value>` directive be `control-id`?

Comment: The `ng-model` directive does not change the value of its own attribute. It is the expected behavior. This code looks nearly the same as your previous question - [Passing An Ng-Model Value to A Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57460074/passing-an-ng-model-value-to-a-directive)

Comment: The closing tag is wrong. HTML5 will ignore it and subsequent elements will be added as children. This is likely to create unexpected behavior.

Comment: The code was the same. This was a followup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{controlId}}` - this is an interpolation and Angular should calculate the expression behind the braces. That's why you get `id="selectValue"` instead of `id="{{controlId}}"`

`ng-model="model"` it's just a two-way binding which is handled by Angular under the hood, but Angular doesn't change the template in this case. Angular should know what model is binded, values are transferred behind the scenes.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed to know.